# Warning: Cannot reinitialise Datatable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Am using Jquery Datatable to render table.
By default the page wont display any table and there's a search box on the page, on entering a value it will make a call to database and render the datatable according to the response from database.
So now once the datatable is rendered, if I enter a new value in search box and call the datatable to be rendered it gives me above error.
I tried bdestroy and redrawing table but nothing seems to work for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var resultArray = [
    ["290013", "TEST OF ENSEMBLE", "11-25-2016", "", "", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["290015", "XXX5", "10-19-2016", "test", "$33.00", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "2002", "XXX5", "XXX5", "XXX5", "", "1864", "2017", "VERSION", "23004746", "XXX5", "", "One Time", "", "", "", "", "", "", "21004482", "9189", "Feature Set", "20003880", "XXX5", "XXX5", "BASE", "19-APR-2017", "04-18-2017", "3877", "", ""],
    ["290015", "XXX5", "10-19-2016", "test", "$33.00", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "", "", "", "", "", "1865", "Deluxe", "EDITION", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "9190", "Charge", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
  ];

  console.log(JSON.stringify(resultArray));
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columns: [{
      title: 'Item Master Number',
      name: 'ItemMasterNumber'
    }, {
      title: 'Description',
      name: 'Description'
    }, {
      title: 'First Processing Date',
      name: 'FirstProcessingDate'
    }, {
      title: 'Alias',
      name: 'Alias'
    }, {
      title: 'Master Price',
      name: 'MasterPrice'
    }, {
      title: 'Product Id',
      name: 'ProductId'
    }, {
      title: 'Product Description',
      name: 'ProductDescription'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set#',
      name: 'FeatureSetId'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Code',
      name: 'FeatureSetCode'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Name',
      name: 'FeatureSetName'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Description',
      name: 'Feature Set Description'
    }, {
      title: 'Enablement Type',
      name: 'Enablement Type'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Id',
      name: 'FeatureId'
    }, {
      title: 'Attribute Name',
      name: 'AttributeName'
    }, {
      title: 'Attribute Value',
      name: 'AttributeValue'
    }],
    data: resultArray,
    rowsGroup: [
      // Always the array (!) of the column-selectors in specified
      // order to which rows groupping is applied.
      // (column-selector could be any of specified in:
      // https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector)
      'ItemMasterNumber:name', 'Description:name', 'FirstProcessingDate:name', 'Alias:name', 'MasterPrice:name',
      'ProductId:name',
      'ProductDescription:name',
      'FeatureSetId:name',
      'FeatureSetCode:name'
    ],
    pageLength: '20',
  });
});
```

I am calling above code each time the value is entered in the search box and clicked on a button besides it.
All I want is to display the new data on the Datatable.
How can I resolve this error.

Comment: Can you please provide your full code, with the html input box that you are using for search, etc? Thanks.

Comment: Did the below answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JSFiddle/snippet I threw together real quick, please let me know if this helps: https://jsfiddle.net/p9pot11h/5/

```js
var dataTable_ = null;

var resultArray = [
  ["290013", "TEST OF ENSEMBLE", "11-25-2016", "", "", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["290015", "XXX5", "10-19-2016", "test", "$33.00", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "2002", "XXX5", "XXX5", "XXX5", "", "1864", "2017", "VERSION", "23004746", "XXX5", "", "One Time", "", "", "", "", "", "", "21004482", "9189", "Feature Set", "20003880", "XXX5", "XXX5", "BASE", "19-APR-2017", "04-18-2017", "3877", "", ""],
  ["290015", "XXX5", "10-19-2016", "test", "$33.00", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "", "", "", "", "", "1865", "Deluxe", "EDITION", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "9190", "Charge", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
];

var resultArray2 = [
  ["290013", "TEST OF ENSEMBLE", "11-25-2016", "", "", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
];

$(document).ready(function() {

  //console.log(JSON.stringify(resultArray));
  dataTable_ = $('#example').DataTable({
    columns: [{
      title: 'Item Master Number',
      name: 'ItemMasterNumber'
    }, {
      title: 'Description',
      name: 'Description'
    }, {
      title: 'First Processing Date',
      name: 'FirstProcessingDate'
    }, {
      title: 'Alias',
      name: 'Alias'
    }, {
      title: 'Master Price',
      name: 'MasterPrice'
    }, {
      title: 'Product Id',
      name: 'ProductId'
    }, {
      title: 'Product Description',
      name: 'ProductDescription'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set#',
      name: 'FeatureSetId'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Code',
      name: 'FeatureSetCode'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Name',
      name: 'FeatureSetName'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Description',
      name: 'Feature Set Description'
    }, {
      title: 'Enablement Type',
      name: 'Enablement Type'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Id',
      name: 'FeatureId'
    }, {
      title: 'Attribute Name',
      name: 'AttributeName'
    }, {
      title: 'Attribute Value',
      name: 'AttributeValue'
    }],
    data: resultArray,
    rowsGroup: [
      // Always the array (!) of the column-selectors in specified
      // order to which rows groupping is applied.
      // (column-selector could be any of specified in:
      // https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector)
      'ItemMasterNumber:name', 'Description:name', 'FirstProcessingDate:name', 'Alias:name', 'MasterPrice:name',
      'ProductId:name',
      'ProductDescription:name',
      'FeatureSetId:name',
      'FeatureSetCode:name'
    ],
    pageLength: '20',
  });

  $('#search-button').on('click', function() {
    var data = resultArray2;
    var dataToSearch = $('#search').val();
    if (dataToSearch == '') {
      data = [];
    }
    // AJAX CALL TO GET RESULTS HERE

    // SUCCESS FUNCTION TO CALL INSIDE AJAX SUCCESS
    rePopulateTable(data);
  });

});

var rePopulateTable = function(data) {
  dataTable_.clear();
  dataTable_.rows.add(data);
  dataTable_.draw();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <input type="button" id="search-button" value="Search DB" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <table id="example">

  </table>
</body>
```